# How do I add a row without affecting other tables of the same class?

Tags: jquery, html-table

Here's my script using append:

```
$("a.addrow").click(function(){
        $(".itemlist").append('<tr><td>Content</td></tr>');
    });
```

And I have this HTML

```
<table class="itemlist">
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="#" class="addrow">Add Row</a>

<table class="itemlist">
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="#" class="addrow">Add Row</a>
```

Now the problem is, this will add row to both tables instead of the relevant one. How do I do that? And how do I prevent anchor jumping, since I'm using # for href?

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.addrow").click(function(event){
    //Get the first match and append the data, if you want another result, you could use .eq().
    //So .eq(0) === .first()
    $(".itemlist").first().append('<tr><td>Content</td></tr>');

    //Prevent the anchor 'jumping'
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Another way to target a specific table would be to add a distinctive class or id, but I guess that's not an option here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answer. Anyway, I'm new to javascript and such, but how do I use eq for each of the table, cuz I have like 7 tables of such with add row buttons. 

I don't want to use distinction because there's a lot of table to id.

Comment: You could use `.filter()` on `$(".itemlist")` to filter unwanted results or `each()` to apply a function to each one of them. I could write an example for you but I don't understand witch table is relevant witch isn't

Comment: Here's the fiddle for you to understand my problem: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/CYs87/3/). But I've figured a way out. I put the button in every `table.itemlist`, and used `.closest()` to find the respective `tr`, it's not semantic, but it'll do for the time being. However, in the fiddle, I still can't figure it out.

Comment: You can see the working example at [LINK](http://mrjunior.my/rolodex/rashada/create-2.html)